# Recaptcha 3 does show on Authentication Popup

Tags: recaptcha, customer-login, authentication

Recaptcha v3 invisible does not display on authentication popup and when the login button is clicked it show the error - This is a required. See below.

[image]

When I looked at the browser console, I can see the below JS error

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "afterRender:
> function(){return renderReCaptcha() }" Message: Cannot read properties
> of undefined (reading 'rendering')
> at UiClass.initCaptcha (reCaptcha.js:116:35)
> at UiClass.renderReCaptcha

This shows that rendering option was not passed to the reCaptcha.js file. See below.

The error occurs here `this.settings.rendering` since this.settings is undefine.

[image]

When I look at the `authentication-popup.phtml` and print out the value of `$block->getJsLayout()`, I could see that rendering is passed to `Magento_Ui/js/core/app`

```
"#authenticationPopup": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            }
```

What I could not figure out is why the rendering disappears when reCaptcha.js is rendered which causes the error above.

I will appreciate any help in solving the issue.